# Why entering esc button will focus the element?

Tags: html, google-chrome, accessibility

The question is about a simple demo:

```html
<div tabindex="0">Tabbable due to tabindex.</div>
```

Since the text element has a `tabIndex` property, it can be focused and appear the outline when entering keyboard `Tab` button. But when I first click the text element and then entering `Esc` button, it also appears the outline. How to explain that?

Comment: *"when I first click the text element*" - Clicking the element gives it the focus? [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o6krwu7q/)

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, from your demo, it is be focued. But why it only appear the outline when I enter esc button?

Comment: I don't get any outline when clicking the element and pressing ESC - Which browser are you testing this on

Comment: @DarkBee Chrome for mac

Comment: No problem for Firefox. I just checked with Chrome. FYI: The state the div gets is not `:focus` but `:focus-visible`

Comment: @DarkBee Yes. But I still don't know why chrome will give a `:focus-visible` when entering esc button. Maybe it want to use a highlight style to tell users which element they are currently exiting from ?

Comment: Here is some more background on [:focus-visible vs :focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible#focus_vs_focus-visible) - TLDR - FWICT: It's (mostly) to inform text browers where the current focus was/is